# Log4j2.xml not found but log4j2-test.xml is

Tags: java, spring, maven, log4j, log4j2

I'm upgrading from log4j 1.x to log4j 2, and have updated my log4j.xml configuration file to a new log4j2.xml configuration. I'm running maven, spring, and mule.

When running a test maven build, the log4j2.xml file is not being picked up. However, if I rename the file log4j2-test.xml, it gets picked up (for instance the console logger with a custom PatternLayout works correctly the second case, but in the first case the default config is used).

Why would log4j pick up the log4j2-test.xml but not the log4j2.xml?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `log4j2-test.xml` has a [higher load precedence](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration) than `log4j2.xml`, you probably have another log4j2 configuration file somewhere on your classpath that's overriding your `log4j2.xml`.  Try finding the location of which conf file is getting pulled by having the following code execute when you run your maven test build:

```
for (String confFile : Arrays.asList("/log4j2-test.xml", "/log4j2.yaml", "/log4j2.yml", "/log4j2.json", "/log4j2.jsn", "/log4j2.xml")) {
    URL resource = YourTestClass.class.getResource(confFile);
    if (resource != null) {
        System.out.format("found %s in: %s\n", confFile, resource.getFile());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @heenenee, after doing this I was able to determine that mule-core generates its own log4j2-test.xml which takes precedence. Now I need to figure out how to overwrite or ignore that file, or stop it from being generated or put on the classpath.